# How to print one design report viewer to produce 3 copies at once with specific headers and footers in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, report, rdlc, reportviewer

How to print one design report viewer to produce 3 copies at once with certain headers and footers in vb.net.

Can I implement it with code please guide me.
Can I apply it in one design reportviewer with the results desired?

Thanks

```
Public Sub New()
            InitializeComponent()
        End Sub

        Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            Dim order = OrderBusiness.GetOrder()
            Me.OrderBindingSource.DataSource = order
            Me.OrderDetailBindingSource.DataSource = order.OrderDetails
            Me.reportViewer1.RefreshReport()
        End Sub

    Public Class Order
        Public Property CustomerName() As String
        Public Property OrderDetails() As List(Of OrderDetail)
    End Class
    Public Class OrderDetail
        Public Property ProductName() As String
        Public Property UnitPrice() As Integer
        Public Property Quantity() As Integer
        Public Property Discount() As Integer
    End Class
    Public Class OrderBusiness
        Public Shared Function GetOrder() As Order
            Return New Order() With {
                .CustomerName = "John Doe",
                .OrderDetails = New List(Of OrderDetail)() From {
                    New OrderDetail() With {
                        .ProductName = "Foo",
                        .UnitPrice = 100,
                        .Quantity = 1,
                        .Discount = 0
                    },
                    New OrderDetail() With {
                        .ProductName = "Bar",
                        .UnitPrice = 200,
                        .Quantity = 2,
                        .Discount = 50
                    },
                    New OrderDetail() With {
                        .ProductName = "Baz",
                        .UnitPrice = 50,
                        .Quantity = 3,
                        .Discount = 0
                    }
                }
            }
        End Function
    End Class
```

The result I want is like this

[image: Report1rdlc]
[image: Report1rdlc-COPY1]
[image: Report1rdlc-COPY2]

Comment: When you press the print button, do you not get the option to specify the number of copies then?

Comment: @jmcilhinney , `When you press the print button, do you not get the option to specify the number of copies then?` 
yes, it's true what you said there is a copy option but I want the results of 3 copies with each different header and footer like the one I posted

Answer (score 0):

You can modify classes declaration adding a `Copy` class.
Use this class to compile header/footer and set page break.

```
Public Class Order
    Public Property CustomerName() As String
    Public Property Copies() As List(Of Copy)
End Class

Public Class Copy
    Public Property Footer() As String
    Public Property Header() As String
    Public Property OrderDetails() As List(Of OrderDetail)
End Class

Public Class OrderDetail
    Public Property ProductName() As String
    Public Property UnitPrice() As Integer
    Public Property Quantity() As Integer
    Public Property Discount() As Integer
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, please guide me how do I do it in report viewer because I am a beginner in report viewer